# How to cut async.series flow in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, series

I use `async.series` as;

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
      callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        if(condition is satified){
           //continue to the next function  
           callback();        
        }else{
           /*condition is not satisfied, do not continue cut the async.series
       and continue to from
        //continue from here part  */
        }

    },
    function(callback) {
       //if condition in second function is not satisfied skip
       callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
       //if condition in second function is not satisfied skip 
       callback();
    }
]);

//continue from here
```

For example assume that there is a condition in second function. If the condition is not satified I want to cut the `async.series`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the callback with error not null:

```
callback(something);
```

instead of:

```
callback();
```

You will be able to get that error here, if you add the callback do `async.series`:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        if (someCondition) {
            // this will stop the async.series flow:
            return callback('some error');
        }
        // this will continue the async.series flow:
        callback();
    },
    // more functions go here
], (err) => {
    if (err) {
        // here you will get the error that was signaled
        // by some of the functions
    } else {
        // everything completed with no errors
    }
});
```

If all of your functions return a different error then you can inspect which one of those terminated the `async.series` flow.

Answer (score 0):

The `callback` function takes 2 arguments. Its signature is -

```
callback(error, data);
```

If you receive error in your second function then you can pass that error in the callback. As a result your `series()` function will stop executing and its error handler will be called. So do like this -

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
      callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        if(condition is satified){
           //continue to the next function  
           callback();        
        }else{
           callback('This is an error');
           /*condition is not satisfied, do not continue cut the async.series
        and continue to from
        //continue from here part  */
    }
], function(error, result){
    if(error){
        // execution is stopped at 2nd function
        console.log(error); // This is an error
    }
});
```